# In Saekano episode 0, what is the context of this censored word?

Tags: saenai-heroine-no-sodatekata

So the censored word is around 16 minutes, during the scene where the girls are drunk from eating liquor-filled chocolate and tie Tomoya up to play a prank on him, Tomoya says

> What have you done?!
>   The **O won't be...

I'm not sure what was censored with "**O".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's likely referring to the [BPO](http://www.bpo.gr.jp/?page_id=1092), the (Japanese) Broadcasting Ethics & Program Improvement Organization:

> A non-profit, non-governmental organization that serves to improve the quality of broadcasting and promote higher ethical standards while ensuring freedom of speech and expression.
>
> BPO deals with complaints and ethical issues by conducting investigations into problematic programs and giving recommendations and/or opinions to either all broadcasters or to the particular broadcaster concerned.

This is one of many meta jokes from this episode.

[image: The who in the what now?]